# Using java.time classes in older Android, such as DayOfWeek

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

The application I'm working on is related to the weekly calendar.

I want to fetch the days of the week. The code below for this is fully working. But I have to lower the API level of the project to 26 -> 24. Thus, some codes become inoperable at API 24 level.

How can I go about this in an alternative way?

**My Code:**

```
fun daysOfWeekFromLocale(): Array<DayOfWeek> {

val firstDayOfWeek = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault()).firstDayOfWeek
var daysOfWeek = DayOfWeek.values()

if (firstDayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.MONDAY) {
    val rhs = daysOfWeek.sliceArray(firstDayOfWeek.ordinal..daysOfWeek.indices.last)
    val lhs = daysOfWeek.sliceArray(0 until firstDayOfWeek.ordinal)
    daysOfWeek = rhs + lhs
}

return daysOfWeek
}
```

**Android studio's Red Lines:**

[image: Function Image]

(In all cases this function should return the same value. -- Array< DayOfWeek > )

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## API “de-sugaring”

The latest Android tooling brings to earlier Android most of the *java.time* functionality built into Android 26+ via [“API desugaring”](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring).

## *Three-TenABP*

If that does not work for you, use the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library, an Android-specific adaptation of [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

---

For more details, see [*How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706). See Answers [by kael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/642706) and [by me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61603915/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]